# Condition filtering SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, window-functions

I have a table
Table name - commands

| id | name | status | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id - number | name - string | status - 0 or 1 | group_id - number |

I need to sort as follows: for all elements with the same group_id I have to check if at least one has a status of 1, if so, then leave, if not, then remove such a group and so on for all group_id

I tried to do it through GROUP BY, and then using HAVING to remove unnecessary groups, but this way I don't get the whole table to be displayed or a query that does not work.

I think it should look like:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM commands GROUP BY group_id HAVING *condition*
```

Please let me know if there are any other commands to use.

| id | name | status | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | name1 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | name2 | 0 | 1 |
| 3 | name3 | 0 | 2 |
| 4 | name4 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | name5 | 1 | 2 |
| 6 | name6 | 0 | 3 |
| 7 | name7 | 1 | 4 |

Result:

| id | name | status | group_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | name3 | 0 | 2 |
| 4 | name4 | 1 | 2 |
| 5 | name5 | 1 | 2 |
| 7 | name7 | 1 | 4 |

Comment: Show us some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text (no images, no links.) I.e. a [mcve].

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Postgresql?

Comment: I am using postgresql

Comment: @jarlh added an example

Answer (score 1):

In Postgres, that's a good spot to use a boolean window function:

```
select *
from (
    select t.*, bool_or(status = 1) over(partition by group_id) has_status_1
    from mytable t
) t
where has_status_1
```

`bool_or` checks if any row in the group satisfies its predicate ; we can use this information for filtering.

The upside is that the table is scanned only once, as opposed to the correlated subquery solution.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `EXISTS` operator with a correlated subquery as the following:

```
SELECT id, name, status, group_id
FROM table_name T
WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM table_name D WHERE D.group_id = T.group_id AND D.status=1)
ORDER BY id
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/V7QnBJd-).